# VS Code Interactive Window Squeezing Figures

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently creating figures in VS Code with Python (using .py file with interactive window). Previously, figures would plot and show up in the Interactive Window and resize to the width of the window. This meant that there was no strange squeezing or resizing of the figures. This seems to have changed overnight and now the figures are not displaying with their appropriate dimensions, and are instead horizontally squeezed. Is there a way through which I can adjust this to return back to simply resizing the figure, rather than squeezing it to have it fit in the window? Thank you!

[plt.savefig output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRNI1.png) [Interactive Window Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJmrY.png) [Image quality has notably deteriorated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjxjZ.png)

Comment: Add a screenshot of the problem, please

Comment: interesting.  presumably the files are perfectly fine when printed as `jpeg` or `png` files... ?

Comment: Precisely, see the plt.savefig output as an example of the correctly rendered version compared to the interactive window output. It is rather curious since this issue seems to have just emerged.

Comment: Could you provide an extended version of Python? Try using the stable version or rolling back to the old version to see if it can be solved.